# Kibana equivalent for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

We've fed up with instability and unpredictability of ELK stack but still in love with the Kibana dashboards.

Hence I'm looking for some potential migration paths. MongoDB looks very promising: huge track record, lots of docs, ability to cope with json easily etc.

Is there some equivalent to Kibana working on top of MongoDB? Some web app which lets you easily run search queries over indexed data, make them into dashboards, add nice maps and diagrams etc.

I've looked into https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/administration-interfaces/ but this seems to be more about managing MongoDB itself rather than playing with data in it.

Comment: https://redash.io/integrations/

Comment: mongodb charts are about to launch

Answer (score 1):

you could have a look at `mongodb-compass` [click here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/products/compass/)

if you would want more, the new mongodb 3.2 has features to connect to any BI tool, like talend. [Read more here](https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-3.2)

Comment: but is it possible to access mongodb-compass via browser like it is possible in Kibana?